# Использование treeView для отображения XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

Можно ли к каждому узлу treeView  привязать XElemnt из XML?
В методе Nodes.Add я не нашел привязку объектов. Может я что-то упустил...?

Например, я хочу, что бы при выборе названия узла из дерева, отображать все его атрибуты где-нибудь. Или мне по любому придется какую-то выборку из исходного XML делать?

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от структуры исходного XML и от того, в каком виде нужно получить данные.

Допустим, имеется документ с информацией о людях следующего содержания:

```
<Persons>
  <Person id="1">
    <FirstName>Вася</FirstName>
    <LastName>Пупкин</LastName>
    <Address Country="РФ">
      <City>Тагил</City>
      <Street>Ленина</Street>
    </Address>
  </Person>
  <Person id="007">
    <FirstName>James</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bond</LastName>
    <Address Country="UK">
      <City>London</City>
      <Street>Lennon</Street>
    </Address>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

Применяем классический обход дерева:

```
void WalkTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes, XElement element)
{
    if (element.HasElements)
    {
        var node = nodes.Add(element.Name.LocalName);

        foreach (var attr in element.Attributes())
            node.Nodes.Add(attr.Value);

        foreach (var elem in element.Elements())
            WalkTree(node.Nodes, elem);
    }
    else
        nodes.Add(element.Value);
}
```

Используем:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
WalkTree(treeView.Nodes, doc.Root);
treeView.ExpandAll();
```

В данном случае я у элементов, имеющих потомков, беру имя, после чего прохожу по их потомкам. А у каждого листового элемента, не имеющего потомков, заношу в дерево значение. Атрибуты равноценны листовым элементам.

Варьировать код можно как угодно.

Comment: Немного, не этого я хочу. Хочется чего-нибудь такого, как при работе с компонентами, которые имеют DataSource. Т.е я могу подключить любой объект и указать, что будет воображаться пользователю.

Comment: @iluxa1810 - Я понимаю, чего хочется. Но, такой привязки у дерева нет. Нужно либо искать сторонний компонент, либо самому писать код, благо он простой.